# findAll() where not in table Yiiframework

Tags: php, sql, yii, models

He there,

I have two tables in my database: "Achievements" and "AchievementsCompleted". I would like to select all of the Achievements unless there is an AchievementCompleted entry with that achievement as foreign key constraint.

So for example:

There are 3 rows in the table Achievement:

- ID: 1 - Achievement1
- ID: 2 - Achievement2
- ID: 3 - Achievement3

and there is one entry in the table AchievementCompleted:

- achievement_id = 2 completed by user 3

In that case I would like the output to be only the models of id 1 and 3 for user 3.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->condition = "";
$models = Achievements::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Thanks in advance! I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Check documentation of cdbcriteria for `join ` or `relation with`

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example? The documentation is too vague imo. Thanks.

Comment: You could try writing your own query and use findAllBySql()

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->join ='INNER JOIN AchievementsCompleted';
$criteria->condition = "AchievementsCompleted.achievement_id != Achievements.id";
$models = Achievements::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a RIGHT JOIN:

Here's you're getting all the Achievements which aren't "Completed":

```
   $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
   $criteria->join='RIGHT JOIN Achievements ON AchievementsCompleted.Achievement_id=Achievements.id';
   $models = AchievementsCompleted::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

You need to replace the Table Columns with your own columns ("Achievement_id" and "id").

Here's a visual graph explaining how SQL Joins work:
[What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Comment: He Wissam, this actually gives me a list of the achievements that are completed. How can I spin this around to a list of not completed achievements? Thanks!

This is what I have according to your example: 

        $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
        $criteria->join='RIGHT JOIN tbl_achievements ON t.achievement_id=tbl_achievements.id';
        $criteria->condition = 'user_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->id;
        $models = AchievementsCompleted::model()->findAll($criteria);